# How to ignore existing css on a page when rendering html in a panel on the page

Tags: css, panel

I have a webpage that is using wcDocker to manage the layout of the page. Currently, I am opening inserting html code directly into a panel

```
panel.$container.find('html_area').html(generatedHTML)
```

Where the generatedHTML is the html of the new page. Opening generatedHTML in a new tab/window will yield the correctly formatted page, but inserting generatedHTML into the panel creates some formatting issues where the generatedHTML inherits existing properties from the page.

I am looking for a way to ignore the existing css and only use the css from the generatedHTML. Apologies if this is a simple issue, I am very unfamiliar with css.

I have tried embedding the css rule

```
all: unset;
```

but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If the target element has an ID of `html_area`, you could use a descendent selector of `*` to target all children of that element

```
#html_area * {
    all: unset;
}
```

This should be inserted at the end of your existing CSS file to unset any inherited properties.

More about descendent selectors https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shadow DOM to encapsulate your content from the document.
`panel.$container.find('html_area').html('');` is only needed if you want to clear the content before you insert the generated HTML.

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
container.shadowRoot.innerHTML = generatedHTML;
panel.$container.find('html_area').html('');
panel.$container.find('html_area').appendChild(container);
```